# Splice delete the last element

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to delete an element of an array with splice, but .splice is deleting the last element all the time. The index that I am passing is correct. What am I doing wrong?

```
$scope.deleteSingleAnswer = function (index) {
  console.log(index);
  console.log($scope.editAnswers);
  $scope.editAnswers.splice(index);
  console.log($scope.editAnswers);
};
```

Comment: you need to specify the amount of items to be deleted i.e. `splice(index,1)` if you don't and if the index is `$scope.editAnswers.length-2` and I think it is, the items that come after that are deleted, which in your case is the last item

Comment: Read the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify how many elements to delete after that particular index. see here

> The splice() method changes the content of an array by removing
>   existing elements and/or adding new elements.

```
var myFish = ["angel", "clown", "mandarin", "surgeon"];
myFish.splice(2, 0, "drum");
```

> Syntax

```
array.splice(start)
array.splice(start, deleteCount)
array.splice(start, deleteCount, item1, item2, ...)
```

> Parameters
>
> start Index at which to start changing the array (with origin 0). If
>   greater than the length of the array, actual starting index will be
>   set to the length of the array. If negative, will begin that many
>   elements from the end of the array.
>
> deleteCount Optional
>
> An integer indicating the number of old array elements to remove. If
>   deleteCount is 0, no elements are removed. In this case, you should
>   specify at least one new element. If deleteCount is greater than the
>   number of elements left in the array starting at start, then all of
>   the elements through the end of the array will be deleted. If
>   deleteCount is omitted, deleteCount will be equal to (arr.length -
>   start). item1, item2, ... Optional The elements to add to the array,
>   beginning at the start index. If you don't specify any elements,
>   splice() will only remove elements from the array.

Answer (score 1):

Try this ...

```
$scope.deleteSingleAnswer = function (index) {
  console.log(index);
  console.log($scope.editAnswers);
  $scope.editAnswers.splice(index, 1);
  console.log($scope.editAnswers);
};
```

Specify how many to remove with `.splice` or it will remove from index to the end of the array.

From MDN:

```
array.splice(start)
array.splice(start, deleteCount)
array.splice(start, deleteCount, item1, item2, ...)
```

If `deleteCount` is omitted, `deleteCount` will be equal to (arr.length - start).

Answer (score 0):

use the **filter** method if you have **id** of every element.

```
const newArr = arrayOfObjects.filter((id) => {
  return id !== 4;
})
```

**It** will give you a new array without **4**.